# Sqlite Auto Increment Error while creating table

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to create a table in sqlite3 using the following query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accounts` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT,
    `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTOINCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I am getting an error `Error: near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error`

How can we solve and create a table according to the above query ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS accounts (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, username varchar(50) NOT NULL, password varchar(255) NOT NULL, email varchar(100) NOT NULL
);` see **https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [sqlite AUTOINCREMENT doc section 3](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

> Because AUTOINCREMENT keyword changes the behavior of the ROWID selection algorithm, AUTOINCREMENT is not allowed on WITHOUT ROWID tables or on any table column other than INTEGER PRIMARY KEY. Any attempt to use AUTOINCREMENT on a WITHOUT ROWID table or on a column other than the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column results in an error.